# Spark Structured Streaming Batch Read Checkpointing

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am fairly new to Spark and am still learning. One of the more difficult concepts I have come across is checkpointing and how Spark uses it to recover from failures. I am doing batch reads from Kafka using Structured Streaming and writing them to S3 as Parquet file as:

```
dataset
    .write()
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
    .partitionBy("date_hour")
    .parquet(getS3PathForTopic(topicName));
```

The checkpoint location is a S3 filesystem path. However, as the job runs, I see no checkpointing files. In subsequent runs, I see the following log:

```
21/10/14 12:20:51 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-relation-54f0cc87-e437-4582-b998-a33189e90bd7-driver-0-5, groupId=spark-kafka-relation-54f0cc87-e437-4582-b998-a33189e90bd7-driver-0] Found no committed offset for partition topic-1
```

This indicates that the previous run did not checkpoint any offsets for this run to pick them up from. So it keeps consuming from the earliest offset.

How can I make my job pick up new offsets? Note that this is a batch query as described [here](http://21/10/14%2012:20:51%20INFO%20ConsumerCoordinator:%20%5BConsumer%20clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-relation-54f0cc87-e437-4582-b998-a33189e90bd7-driver-0-5,%20groupId=spark-kafka-relation-54f0cc87-e437-4582-b998-a33189e90bd7-driver-0%5D%20Found%20no%20committed%20offset%20for%20partition%20hypertrace-raw-service-view-events-1).

This is how I read:

```
             sparkSession
                .read()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaProperties.bootstrapServers())
                .option("subscribe", topic)
                .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL")
                .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", sslConfig.truststoreLocation())
                .option("kakfa.ssl.truststore.password", sslConfig.truststorePassword())
                .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", sslConfig.keystoreLocation())
                .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", sslConfig.keystorePassword())
                .option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "")
                .option("failOnDataLoss", "true");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why `batch` Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka still exists now. If you wish to use it, then you must code your *own* `Offset management`. See the guide, but it is badly explained.

I would say `Trigger.Once` is a better use case for you; `Offset management` is provided by Spark as it is thus not batch mode.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the trigger once option.